# IOS native plugin for universal architecture

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, arm64, arm7

I have a project in Unity3d that uses an iOS native plugin that I made in Xcode.
I use Unity3d v4.6.2 with Scripting Backend option in IL2CPP and Architecture option in "Universal"
Whem I run the project on my ipod5, it works but when I want to archive it, I have errors links with my library:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64
```

with a warning that says

```
file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (arm64)
```

My library configuration is the following

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAm9r.jpg

and my list of iOS simulators is

http://imgur.com/XlSojzT

I try them all and none works

When I run the command

```
lipo -info mylib.a
```

I see the following information

```
input file mylib.a is not a fat file
Non-fat file: mylib.a is architecture: x86_64
```

I need my project to all the architecture, but do not know what else to configure.

Thanks for your help

Comment: It seems that the mylib.a library you are linking is only built for the x64 architecture, which means that it was likely built targeting the Mac machine, not iOS. See if you can change it to build targeting arm64 for iOS.

Comment: I had to create my static library from zero and recreate the script for Unity3D that I use as a bridge. Now, in my Xcode project, I can see "iOS Device" in the list of simulator and I can't choose my iOS device anymore. I don't understand but choosing "iOS device" and build, everything works fine.

Comment: You may need to select the device manually from the Product > Destination menu. I've seen some similar problems with certain Xcode versions.